# How to consume web-service in JSF2 Netbeans project?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, jsf, jsf-2

I know that this question was asked many times, I read many of them but I think I'm missing sth basic, so it doesn't work for me..

(Project is in JSF2, Netbeans 7.3beta, Glassfish3.. and web-services written in WCF) 
What have I already done:

1. Create a JSF2 project.
2. Right click on the project, new web service client. Fill WSDL URL. Finish
3. Create ManagedBean, open it.. drag and drop "DoWork" method from my webservice.
4. Look at my simple code (I've got index.html, where I display DataTable, that is created in my managedbean) 
   index.html

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">     
       <h:head><title>IGNORED</title></h:head>
       <h:body>
           <ui:composition template="/templates/masterPage.xhtml">         
               <ui:define name="content">
                   <h:form>
                      <h3>and #{bean.tst}!</h3>                           
                      <p:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
                          <p:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="column" headerText="#{bean.headers[column]}">
                          #{row[column]}
                          </p:columns>
                      </p:dataTable>  
                   </h:form>
               </ui:define>                        
           </ui:composition>
       </h:body>
   </html>
   ```

and.. bean.java

```
    @Named(value = "bean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class Bean implements Serializable {  
        @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_62599/TestService.svc.wsdl")
        private TestService service;

        ... // list, maps.. not important for this example

        public Bean() {
            columns = new ArrayList<String>();  
            rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();         
            headers = new HashMap<String,String>();

            // Columns:
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)  
            {
                String column_id = "c" + i;
                String column_name = "Column name " + i;           
                columns.add(column_id);                                    
                headers.put(column_id, column_name);            
            }

            // Rows:
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)  
            {               
                Map<String,Object> m = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                m.clear();          
                for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)  
                {
**// HERE IT DOESNT WORK in table i've got Content:Null**
                    m.put("c" + j, "Content:" + Tst); 
                }                                               
                rows.add(m);
            }       
        }

        private String Tst;
        public String getTst() {
            return doWork("Test");
        }

        private String doWork(java.lang.String str) {
            DataTable.ITestService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingITestService();
            return port.doWork(str);
        } 
    }
```

Why I can't use it inside my managed bean? What have I done wrong? I want to use it in bean so I could fill my DataTable...

Comment: I'm not sure this is good answer, but Do I have to use simple java classes to connect with webservices?.. and then use those classes in managedbeans? It works..

Comment: You never assign a value to `Tst` so it will always be null. You will not be able to call the service in the constructor because `service` is injected after the bean is instantiated. Have a look at `@PostConstruct` for initialization.

Comment: @Marshall, you haven't stated what exactly is going wrong. What exception are you getting? Your proposed solution is fine and if implemented properly will go well. As an alternative, you can inject a webservice reference into your managed bean with `@WebServiceRef`. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef.html) for pointers